# The continuous Taylor series; are they just Taylor series?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I first posed this question when I was a first year student. I came up with some ad hoc arguments as to why the result is true (a bit of numerical experimentation), but never had a proof. I forgot about it until the other day, and thought it was still an interesting question. First, some motivation.

Take the expression

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

which equals its own derivative, that much is straight forward. The $x^n$ gets sent to $n x^{n-1}$ and the factorial kills the $n$, and the same expression emerges.

We can do the same thing with the integral.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}\,dy$$

formally satisfies being its own derivative--albeit the expression does not converge (which is a shame). But if you act like it converges, it should converge to $e^x$ because it's its own derivative.

This led me to considering a more suitable case, where the integral actually converges, and considering if the two functions agree. For example,

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2} \frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}\,dy$$

defines a $C^{\infty}$ function in $x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$. This function satisfies $F'(x) = e^{-1}F(\frac{x}{e^2})$.

If we take

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

then equally so, $G'(x) = e^{-1}G(\frac{x}{e^2})$.

> Does $G = F$?

I thought of this in a more general setting though. I wondered if it happened for $e^{-y^2}$, does it work for other functions?

It may be useful to explain the ad hoc arguments I had when I was younger. These arguments were a summation of identities which are satisfied by both expressions, which seems implausible if they weren't equal in some sense. I'll explain them in the obtuse language I used when I was a first year, as it is the best way I can think of framing it. Let $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ denote the following operators,

$$\mathcal{I} \{f\} (x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}\,dy$$

$$\mathcal{S} \{f\} (x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Also, let $Qf(x) = xf(x)$ and $Tf(x) = f(x+1)$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{I}$ behave identically under actions of the two operators. The following similar identities present evidence as to why these two operators may be equivalent in a good enough scenario.

$$\mathcal{I}\{Tf\}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{I} \{f\} (x)$$

$$\mathcal{S} \{Tf\} (x) = \frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{S} \{f\} (x)$$

$$\mathcal{I}\{Qf\}(x) = Q\mathcal{I}\{Tf\}(x) = Q\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{I} \{f\} (x)$$
$$\mathcal{S} \{Qf\} (x) = Q\mathcal{S} \{Tf\} (x) = Q\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{S} \{f\} (x)$$

From these we also get

$$Q \mathcal{I}\{f\}(x) = \mathcal{I}\{QT^{-1}f\}(x)$$
$$Q \mathcal{S}\{f\}(x) = \mathcal{S}\{QT^{-1}f\}(x)$$

From all this the question is simple,

> Are these two operators ever equivalent, if so when?

Or phrased more poetically

> Is the continuous Taylor series no different than the discrete Taylor series?

Comment: You could consider the same integral with any $1$-periodic function of $y$ inserted. They all satisfy the same identity. Are they all equal, up to a constant multiple? I suspect not.

Comment: It's natural to (sort of) rephrase this as: do we have uniqueness for the delay differential equation $y'(x)=cy(ax)$, and (I know nothing about this but) I think not in the sense that $y(1)$ determines $y$; rather you need $y$ on an interval.

Comment: Also, $G$ is entire while $F$ looks like we have a real problem at $x=0$.

Comment: More specifically, it's easy to prove that if $y,w$ are two solutions of $y'(x)=cy(ax)$ and they agree on $[a,1]$, then they are identical. I think that's all that is true here; in other words, the DDE determines the function not up to a multiplicative constant, but up to a function on an interval.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I considered Delay differential equations but never got far (I was a first year undergrad though, maybe relooking into it would be a good idea). Also, $F$ is technically holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}/(-\infty,0)$ but $F$ could be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ if the branch cut is 'removable.' If it isn't this would be a *great* way of showing the functions aren't equal!

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, yes, yes. I should've mentioned that. I didn't mean to say they are *always* equal, but if they *can* equal. And if so why. I'll dig through my old notes, but I'm pretty sure I managed to construct a function where the two functions coincided.

Comment: In fact, elaborating on Will's remark, for any periodic measure $f(x)=\int\ldots\, d\mu(y)$ will satisfy the DDE $f'(x)=cf(ax)$, and perhaps a better question would be, are these all solutions? (Note that your $G$ is the special case $\mu=\sum \delta_n$.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling That would be very interesting indeed. Then the question becomes, when does $f_{\mu_0} = \int...d\mu_0(y) = f_{\mu_1} =\int...d\mu_1(y)$...

Comment: @ChristianRemling I actually think we don't even need an interval to determine uniqueness. Couldn't the sequence $\{e^{-2k}\}_{k=0}^\infty$ suffice. Since if $e^{k^2}F^{(k)}(1)=F(e^{-2k}) = G(e^{-2k}) = e^{k^2} G^{(k)}(1)$ then $F = G$ (which is just the identity theorem in two ways ). Assuming we stick to analytic solutions.

Comment: @james.nixon: By integrating from $-\infty$ you seem to create a continuous analogue not of Taylor series, but of Laurent series with infinitely many negative powers. If you truly wanted to mimick Taylor series, shouldn't you integrate from $0$ instead of from $-\infty$? (This would also cure some divergences, as a byproduct.)

Comment: @AlexM You can do this, but then the operator relationships I wrote earlier don't hold. Those relationships were very important to me. Also, if you think carefully. $e^x = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ because $\frac{1}{n!} = 0$ when $n < 0$. So technically Taylor series do start from negative infinity, the $n!$ cancels out the negative terms. You can think of Laurent series as having a simple pole at the negative terms, which limit with the $1/n!$ to create a finite value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. In fact I will show the map from $1$-periodic signed measures $\mu$ to $$F_\mu(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu(y) e^{-y^2}\frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}dy$$ is injective for "reasonable" signed measures $\mu$.

Indeed, consider what happens to the following expression as $y_0$ goes to $\infty$ while the residue of $y_0$ modulo $1$ remains fixed:

$$ \Gamma(y_0+1)  e^{-y_0^2 - y_0 \operatorname{dlog} \Gamma(y_0+1) } F_{\mu} ( e^{ 2 y_0 + \operatorname{dlog}  \Gamma(y_0+1)} ) $$

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu(y) e^{-y^2 + 2 y y_0 - y_0^2} \frac{ \Gamma(y_0+1) e^{ y \operatorname{dlog} \Gamma(y_0+1)- y_0 \operatorname{dlog} \Gamma(y_0+1)}}{\Gamma(y+1)} dy$$

$$ = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} \mu(y+y_0) e^{-y^2} \frac{ \Gamma(y_0+1) e^{ y \operatorname{dlog} \Gamma(y_0+1)}}{\Gamma(y+y_0+1)} dy$$

Because $\Gamma(y+1)$ is log-convex and its slope is roughly $\log y$, the exponential-linear approximation to the slope gets better as $y_0$ goes to $\infty$, and so this

$$ \approx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu(y+y_0) e^{-y^2} dy $$

uniquely determines the convolution of $\mu$ with the Gaussian. Now because none of the Fourier transform coefficients of the Gaussian vanish, we can extract all the Fourier series coefficients of $\mu$ from this, which under mild analytic conditions extracts $\mu$.

In particular, for your example $F(x)$ we see that $F(e^{2 y_0 + \operatorname{dlog} \Gamma(y_0+1)})$ is asymptotic to a constant times $\frac{   e^{y_0^2 + y_0 \operatorname{dlog} \Gamma(y_0+1) }}{ \Gamma(y_0+1)}$ while this is not true for your Taylor series $G(x)$.

Comment: Ha! That is great! This is actually more interesting! It's always cool when a false result makes the concept better and stronger. Personally, I interpret this to mean we can construct arbitrary "Taylor series" with any 1-periodic measure ($F_\mu(x) = \int...\,d\mu$) and they never equal, but they satisfy the same operator equations I wrote in the question. That is really cool, thanks a ton! Back to sifting through my first year notes...

Comment: One small point: you say and probably mean "measures" (that is, not necessarily absolutely continuous), but you write $\mu(y)\, dy$ instead of $d\mu(y)$, which I find confusing. (The added generality of measures with a possible singular part is useful of course; for example, the power series corresponds to $\mu=\sum\delta_n$.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling Eventually I just assumed he meant $d\mu$ but that also confused me at first. As a side note, I'm also thinking we may be able to prove this more rigorously by using the Fourier Transform. (Adding a variable $a$ and using a coefficient $e^{2\pi a yi}$). At least, I'm close to doing it not for measures, but with holomorphic 1-periodic functions. Not the best at measure theory, more at home with holomorphic functions. I'll answer my own question if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found a way of proving $F \neq G$ using distribution theory. I'm not the best at distribution theory, it's definitely not my field, but I think I'm doing something right. This is as much rigor as I can produce in distribution theory, but I think I'm on the right track. I don't have a referential brain for distribution theory, I'm going off what I can remember, I apologize if I'm not explicitly stating the theorems I'm using. This idea works generally as to why the continuous Taylor series can *never* equal the discrete Taylor series, but I'll be a bit cavalier. Maybe this argument works in more general cases, but one would need to know more about distribution theory to produce such a result, sadly I don't.

Let's just use $e^{-y^2}$ to be explanatory. If we take

$$F(a,x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} e^{-2\pi a y i} \frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}\,dy$$

Then we can look at the equivalency in a Fourier sense.

Take the Poisson summation

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty F(n,x) = \sum _{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum _{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

which follows because $\frac{1}{n!} = 0$ for $n<0$. Now I'm not certain about the following interchange, but I'm fairly certain it should be allowed in good enough scenarios (especially with $e^{-y^2}$).

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty F(n,x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} e^{-2\pi i n y} \frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}\,dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \chi(y)e^{-y^2} \frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}\,dy$$

where $\chi$ is the dirac comb. This is kind of nothing new to what Christian Remling said, except I'm phrasing it distributionally, which is to our advantage as we add the Fourier transform. As least, if I've not mistaken myself. The above expression can be thought of as an inner product. If the discrete and continuous Taylor series equal each other, then $(\chi, h) = (1,h)$ or $(\chi -1, h) =0$, where

$$h(y) = e^{-y^2}\frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}$$

I'm kind of out of my element right here, if I'm wrong, definitely correct me. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the Fourier Transform. Let $\delta$ denote the dirac $\delta$ function

$$\mathcal{F}\{\chi -1\} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi i n y} - \delta = \chi - \delta$$

satisfies

$$(\mathcal{F}\{\chi-1\},h) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2}\frac{x^n}{n!} \neq 0$$

Notice we remove the $n=0$ term. This produces the final result. It is straight forward from here! We just use the unitary properties of $\mathcal{F}$ under this inner product.

$$(\chi-1,\mathcal{F}^{-1}h) \neq 0$$

Apply $\mathcal{F}$ again, using the unitary property again, and through the exact same argument

$$(\chi-1,h) = (\mathcal{F}\{\chi -1\}, \mathcal{F}^{-1}h) = (\chi - \delta, \mathcal{F}^{-1} h)\neq 0 $$

therefore

$$(\chi-1,h) \neq 0$$

The continuous Taylor series cannot equal the discrete Taylor series. Personally, I'm ashamed to ask, but for what functions does this actually work. I know this argument must work in a distributional sense, but for what functions does this actually work when written in a more classical sense?